# Summing up rows with the same row ID

Tags: c#, windows

I have a project and I am trying to sum up rows of the same ID together.

Like for example:

```
ID    Quantity

1     5 
1     7
2     10
2     18
1     8
```

So when I press a button, quantity under ID 1 will give me 20 and for ID 2, I will get 28.
But I faced an error specifying that "Object reference is not set to an instance of an object". Below are my codes:

```
id = int.Parse(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
```

This is the code that shows the error msg:

```
int id = 0;
int qty = 0;
List<QuantityPerID> qtyList = new List<QuantityPerID>();

QuantityPerID qtyObj;

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    id = int.Parse(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
    qty = int.Parse(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
    qtyObj = new QuantityPerID();
    bool ifexists = false;

    if (qtyList != null && qtyList.Count() > 0)
    {
        if (qtyList.Where(q => q.ID == id).Count() > 0)
        {
            ifexists = true;
        }
    }
    if (ifexists)
    {
        qtyObj = qtyList.Where(q => q.ID == id).First();
        qtyObj.Quantity += qty;
    }
    else
    {
        qtyObj.ID = id;
        qtyObj.Quantity = qty;

        qtyList.Add(qtyObj);
    }
}
```

I would like to ask also is there any other easier method to achieve the same results?

Comment: at wich  line you are getting this error

Comment: id = int.Parse(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()); // i am getting the error at this line

Comment: Maybe worth thinking about something else than ID that allows you to group items. The idea of ID is rather that they should be unique.

Comment: I read through different posts and came to know that using system.linq can also work but i dont really know how to code it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that `Cells[0]` and `Cells[1]` are not empty? You are calling the ToString on it's Values. Check if the Value is null before the call to ToString

```
if( null != row.Cells[0].Value )
{
    id = int.Parse(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
}

if(null != row.Cells[1].Value)
{
    qty = int.Parse(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
}
```

Do you see an empty line at the end of the rows? Does the [DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property set to true?
If so, then this is the issue. You are also reading the values of the empty line.
Instead of the foreach, you can do it with a for loop

```
// notice the Count - 1. 
for(var index = 0; index < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; ++index)
{
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: I entered the data manually on the gridview cells. When i debugged it for the first time, the program is able to read my row ID but for the second loop, the error msg popped up

Comment: @EnlightenedCodes do you have an empty row at the end? The auto generated row? If you do, then you are accesing it.

Comment: I do have an empty row after the last data was entered

Comment: Marked but i cant up because i dont have enough reps

Answer (score 0):

Split this definition

```
id = int.Parse(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
```

into multiple parts to see what is generating your NullReferenceException (and possibly the Qty one too).

Or, at runtime, you could check the Cells' values using IntelliSense (if you hover above "Cells", or "row" it will show you their contents".